# Adding MediaMuxer for creating MP4 file

Tags: android, mp4, android-mediacodec

how can add to this code the MediaMuxer to create MP4 video file:

```
public class AvcEncoder {

private MediaCodec mediaCodec;
private BufferedOutputStream outputStream;
private File f;

public AvcEncoder(int w, int h, String file_name) 
{ 
    f = new File(file_name + ".mp4");

    try {
        outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
    } catch (Exception e){ 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



   String key_mime = "video/mp4v-es"; //video/mp4v-es, video/3gpp, video/avc

    mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(key_mime);  
    MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(key_mime, w, h);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, (w * h) << 3);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 25);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);

    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE,MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AVCProfileBaseline);
    mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
    mediaCodec.start();




}

public void close() {
    try {
        mediaCodec.stop();
        mediaCodec.release();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e){ 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// called from other class
public void offerEncoder(byte[] input) {
    try {
        ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mediaCodec.getInputBuffers();
        ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
        int inputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(0);
        if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
            inputBuffer.clear();
            inputBuffer.put(input);
            mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, input.length, 0, 0);
        }

        MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        int outputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
        while (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer outputBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];
            byte[] outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
            outputBuffer.get(outData);
            outputStream.write(outData, 0, outData.length);

            mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
            outputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        //t.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: There are several examples of using `MediaMuxer` on bigflake and in Grafika.  The simplest is probably http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeAndMuxTest, which saves rendered OpenGL frames as a .mp4 file (just search for all uses of `mMuxer`).  If there's a specific area you need help with please call it out in the question.